# PYTHON Re: Performance: Starting from a specific line in a text file read a line and split it based on tabs, then access each element.

Tags: python, python-3.x

As per the title the issue is i want to do the following:

1. Starting from a specific line x up to the end of the file read each line. Nb. i dont want to use readline() as that reads the entire file to memory and when testing it is very slow on the server i deployed it to. (took like 15 minutes, whereas on my very good pc it takes 30sec).
2. when the single line is read i want to .split("  ") that specific line and load it to a list so i can access each element.

Please see my attempt below (editted as sensitive):

```
with open(FileName, "w+") as file:
        file.write(FileName + "," + Quantity + "\n")
        # Start from beginning of data and read each line and take specific data   
        for x in range(StartCount,Quantity+StartCount)):
            os.chdir(FileLocation + country)
            with open(OutputFileName, 'r') as OutputFile:    
                for x, line in enumerate(OutputFile):
                    OutputFileData = [line.split("  ") for line in OutputFile]

                    #Select data you want for file from output file. Nb OutputFileData[1][:-1] removed extra part of a column
                    try:
                        FileData = OutputFileData[0]+ "," + OutputFileData[1][:-1] + "," + OutputFileData[2]
```

.... I then go on to append file data to the file i'm creating.

Note my code works fine when i use:

```
with open(OutputFileName, 'r') as OutputFile:    
                lines=OutputFile.readlines()
                temp = lines[x]
                OutputFileData = temp.split("   ")
```

But as i said before i believe the slowness of the script when i run it on the server is because it keeps iterating over: lines=OutputFile.readlines() which causes it to slow down.. So when i check the file im trying to create i will see it stop at an amount of lines and then it just hangs..

Please help me figure out a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just coming back to say the issue at the time wasn't actually my code its just that the server is really really just that slow. So i ended up having the code run on individual machines and then drop the data to the server where it needed to be. This improved performance immensely.

Answer (score 0):

How about reading in N lines at a time and process those in a 'chunk', then repeat the process.  Something like this:

```

```
textfile = "f:\\mark\\python\\test.txt"


def read_n(file, x):
    with open(file, mode='r') as fh:
        while True:
            data = ''.join(fh.readline() for _ in range(x))

            if not data:
                break

            yield data


for nlines in read_n(textfile, 5):
    print(nlines)
```

```

Which yields (from my simple sample file):

```
abc
123
def
456
ghi

789
jkl
abc
123
def

456
ghi
789
jkl
abc

123
def
456
ghi
789

jkl
abc
123
def
456

ghi
789
jkl
```

I am merely printing the lines in chunks, but you could perform whatever processing you are doing.

Comment: If it reads N lines at a time how will i tell it when to stop as the total number of lines changes for each file (i mean i could possible do some math to divide the total up by a equal number but if its uneven that leads to my next question)? and what happens if for eg it tries to read a chunk of 4 lines but only 2 lines remain left in the file will it throw an error? Also ive never used Yield  what exactly is happening in the code?

Comment: If you look at the output you will see three lines at the end.  if there are less than N lines left, it simply processes the remaining lines.  My example processes 5 lines at a time, but when there are just 3 lines left, it processes those three.  Yield data is returning the N lines of data.